# Getting NoSuchMethodError with TextView Methods

Tags: android, view, textview, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting an `NoSuchMethodError` with a class that I made that extends the `TextView`. The only thing I did was adding it some variables and adding `onLongClickListener`. No more modifications.

Everything is working fine when I use my application in my android phone 4.1.2
But in my friend's phone which is 4.0.3, it throws this `NoSuchMethodError`.

**Here is the code when i create the Class that extends the Textview:**

```
descrip=new TextViewList(context, admin, this);
descrip.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 15);
descrip.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
descrip.setTextAlignment(Gravity.CENTER);                   
descrip.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Descripcion")));
descrip.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
descrip.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
descrip.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
descrip.setBackground(img);
layDescripcion.addView(descrip);
```

First it threw the exception with `setTextAlignment`, then I removed it and threw it again with the `setBackground` method.

What is causing this error? Does that mean that my app isn't compatible with Android
versions below 4.1.2?  I set the minimun to be 2.2 when I created the project. And I am using android.support.v4 libraries where they are requested.

**Here is the LogCat:**

```
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: modelo.TextViewList.setBackground
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at modelo.ListaTextViewList.mostrarGastos(ListaTextViewList.java:92)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at controlador.AdminUI.establecerListaGastoVar(AdminUI.java:138)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at com.ConApps.walletsaver.GastosVariables.onCreate(GastosVariables.java:23)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-09 21:45:26.715: E/AndroidRuntime(13481):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html. checks fro methods supported

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setBackground()` introduced only in `16 api`. Use `setBackgroundDrawable()` instead.

what all phone which has less than 16 api ,they will support `setBackgroundDrawable()`

Comment: so i just have to look for methods supported by old versions of android? in this case, for this project, I set the minimun api to be 8. If there is no method for those older apis, is there any other alternative? Thanks for your answer by the way :)

Comment: the same thing i wrote if you can not use setbackground just use setbackgrounddrawable.this is the alternative only for low versions...if you want more clarification do some R&D . if you like this ans just make it accept

Comment: all right. yeah, tha did the job. Then ill make sure to use the correct methods to support lower version. Thanks for the help Mr King Cobra

Answer (score 6):

This is a workaround for this problem:

```
Drawable d = this.res.getDrawable(R.drawable.metro_circle);
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN ) {
    metroIconTextView.setBackground(d);
}
else {
    metroIconTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```